# Whats the meaning of **(&d) in c?

Tags: c, pointers

our teacher gave us the following code:

```
x = **(&d);
```

His question was: "Which lines of codes do you have to add above this line, so that the code is correct?"

Can anybody help me? What is the meaning of this line?

Comment: Please mention the type of `x` and `d`  ?

Comment: (&d) is the adress of d, then you dereference it. Now you dereference what is stored in d. Which is basically an undefined behavior.

Comment: `int a = 0; int* d = &a; int x; x = **(&d);` There.

Comment: Show us that you've made an effort. What do the individual operators mean? What is the order of operations? What do you think the intermediate results are?

Comment: @TonyTannous How can we say it's undefined it we don't know what d is and how it's init'd?

Comment: @Achal That is probably part of the test.

Comment: Your edit turned the question into nonsense that can't compile.  `*(&a)` has type `int` because of `int a`, and `int` is not a valid operand for unary `*` dereference.  Also the answers depended on the current phrasing and example in the question, so it also invalidated the answer.  I'll roll it back for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remark of DeiDei is a possibility, I just explain more here

We are in C, and to simplify consider *x* and *d* are not macros.

`x = **(&d);` is equivalent to `x = *d;` because to get the address then dereference does nothing

Now the question is to find a context where `x = *d;` is legal, for that *d* has to be a pointer. Let say `int * d;`

Probably also the goal is to not have a segmentation fault so *d* need to memorize a valid address. Let say `int a; int * d = &a;`

Now we assign *x* with `*d` so the type of *x* must be compatible with *int* Let say `int a; int * d = &a; x = **(&d);`

To be clean we do not want to access to an uninitialized value, because *x* finally receive the value of *a* that one must be initialized.

`int a = 0; int* d = &a; int x; x = **(&d);` from DeiDei is compatible with the requirement, but of course they are plenty of other solutions

Answer (score 0):

```
x = **(&d);
```

is equivalent to

```
x = **&d;
```

is equivalent to

```
x = *(*&d);
```

also for any variable `v` this

```
v == *&v
```

holds true.

From the above it concludes that

```
*&d == d
```

so

```
x = *(*&d);
```

equals

```
x = *d;
```

As the dereference operator `*` can only be applied to a pointer it follows the `d` has to be of a pointer type

```
T * d; /* Let be T any type. This defined d to be pointer to that type T. */
```

Applying to a variable of type `T*` the operator `*` the result evaluates to the type `T` itself.

As it is given

```
x = *d
```

from this it concludes that `x` needs to be of type `T`.

So the line in question needs to be

```
T x, *d;
```

or in a more readable form

```
T x;
T * d;
```

:-)